# Show linearity of this map

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

We have the following maps on a complex vector space $V$

$\phi : V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $g : V^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} , x,y,w \in V$.

$\phi $ satisfies that 
$\phi(\lambda x ) = |\lambda|^2 \phi(x)$ and $\phi(x+y) + \phi(x-y) = 2(\phi(x) + \phi(y))$

and the map $g$ that is defined by $\phi$ via the polarization identity:

$$g(x,y) = \frac{1}{4} ( \phi(x+y) - \phi(x-y) + i \phi(x+iy) - i \phi(x-iy)$$

Now I want to show that $g$ is linear, but so far I was only able to show that $g(-x,y) = -g(x,y)$ and $g(x+y,w)=  g(x,w) + g(y,w)$. But what I want to show is that $g(\lambda x,y) = \lambda g(x,y)$. (The other coordinate would be pretty much the same, so I just consider the first one.) Does anybody have an idea how this could work?

Comment: Is $\;\phi\;$  a map... *to where*? Where is $\;g\;$ defined? Is $\;x\;$ complex in the definition of $\;\phi\;$ but then real in the definition of $\;g\;$ ? So many things to explain...

Comment: The next step is to show that $g(ix,y) = ig(x,y)$. Then, with what you have, you know that $g(\lambda x,y) = \lambda g(x,y)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, this would not be a problem, but I am missing the continuity argument.

Comment: It may be that you need to assume continuity of $\phi$. Off-hand, I don't see how it would follow from the assumptions.

Comment: @DanielFischer there is nothing about continuity in the exercise, so I guess it has to hide somewhere.

Comment: Is it possible that $\phi$ is real and non-negative?

Comment: @T.A.E. it is not written in the exercise, but maybe we can show it.

Comment: It is enough to show that $Q_{x,y}(\alpha)=q(x+\alpha y)$ is continuous at $\alpha=0$ for every fixed $x$, $y$. You're close because $Q_{x,y}(\alpha)+Q_{x,y}(-\alpha)=2|\alpha|^{2}q(y)+2q(x)$ is continuous at $\alpha=0$. But oh so far away.

Comment: @T.A.E. I honestly did not understand your comment, would you mind explaining this a little bit more?

Comment: @TobiasHurth : Because of additivity, you can show that $g(\alpha x,y)=\alpha g(x,y)=g(x,\overline{\alpha}y)$ for all $\alpha \in\mathbb{C}$ with rational real and imaginary parts. For a general $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ let $\{ \alpha_{n}\}$ converge to $\beta$. Then $g(\beta x,y)-\beta g(x,y)=\lim_{n} g(\beta x,y)-g(\alpha_{n} x,y)=\lim_{n}g((\beta-\alpha_{n})x,y)$ can be written in terms of $\lim_{n}\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^{n}\phi(y+(-1)^{n}(\beta-\alpha_{n})x)$. So the scalar property is equivalent to showing that $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0}\phi(y+\alpha x)=\phi(y)$ for all $x,y\in V$.

Comment: ah, but do you know how to show the last limit or is this the problem?

Comment: I don't know, but $\phi(\lambda x)=|\lambda|^{2}\phi(x)$ is an added assumption that gives $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0}[\phi(y+\alpha x)+\phi(y-\alpha x)]=2\phi(y)$, but I don't see how to separate out the two cases of $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$. I do know that assuming $\phi \ge 0$ gives it because, then, $\phi(x)^{1/2}$ because a seminorm. This is strange business closely related to the axiom of choice through the same basic construction used to create non-measurable sets. In fact, if $\alpha\mapsto \phi(x+\alpha y)$ is Lebesgue measurable, then, as I recall, it's also continuous!